# QNetworkAccessManager uploads fail

Tags: qt, qnetworkaccessmanager

In the app I upload a video file (24Mb about) every 2 minutes and this works well. It works also if I upload a new file after the previous one have ended.

Two minutes is enough time for the file to upload, but if the connection is slow and a new file tries to upload the app hungs.

Can I somehow have two uploads at the same time?

My code:

```
QString MainWindow::rename_video()
{
    QString oldName="C:/Qt/Qt5.10.1/Nuevo/build_principal_16/riderout.mp4";
    QString newName=QString::number(QDateTime::currentMSecsSinceEpoch())+".mp4";
    QFile f(oldName);

    if (f.rename(newName)) {
        // upload
        m_file = new QFile("C:/Qt/Qt5.10.1/Nuevo/build_principal_16/"+newName);

        QFileInfo fileInfo(*m_file);

        QUrl url("ftp://jumpemirates.com/app/history/"+newName);
        url.setUserName("user@email.com");
        url.setPassword("password");
        url.setPort(21);

        if (m_file->open(QIODevice::ReadOnly))
            QNetworkReply *reply = m_manager->put(QNetworkRequest(url), m_file);
    } else {
        qWarning("Unable to rename video file.");
        return "";
    }

    return newName;
}

void MainWindow::uploadFinished(QNetworkReply *reply) {
    if (!reply->error()) {
        m_file->close();
        m_file->deleteLater();
        reply->deleteLater();
    }
}
```

Comment: Excuse my poor knowledge, I do not understand what I should share

Comment: If I interpret the code correctly, you basically change a pointer (m_file) in your rename_video function which is used by the previous upload, while it is still uploading. That calls for trouble! Also, I hope the username and password in your example are not the actual username and password for the live system.

Comment: Also, you will close the file and delete the pointer when the first upload finishes, if that one ever does finish correctly, but the remaining upload still needs that pointer.

Comment: Thank you Rolf for your answer, I will look for other examples and I will try. The user and pass are not real, thanks